# grouping two data frames and looping over with stringdist_join

Tags: r, fuzzyjoin

I want to do a fuzzy match of American counties by decade using stringdist_join. Since county names change over time I want to match to the correct county name in each decade.

If I write:

```
stringdist_join(mispelled,correct,by=c('decade','county'))
```

Then stringdist_join will do a fuzzy match on the decade too, matching e.g. 1960 to 1970, when in fact I want to treat the decade variable as correct and only fuzzy match the counties.

I can see that I need to group mispelled and correct dataframes by decade then run on each separately, but I don't know how to do this. Tidyverse solutions would be preferred.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, I think the method you seek is to allow `max_dist` to be a vector of distances, where you might do `stringdist_inner_join(..., max_dist=c(0,2))`. Unfortunately, while that has been requested (in 2017: https://github.com/dgrtwo/fuzzyjoin/issues/36 and https://github.com/dgrtwo/fuzzyjoin/issues/21), it does not appear to be implemented yet.

A work-around, if you can afford the larger intermediate join product, is to allow it and then filter out where `decade` is an inexact join.

Lacking data, I'll demonstrate using `ggplot2::diamonds`. Here, I'll want normal `stringdist` functionality for `cut` and exact matches for `clarity`.

```r
d <- data.frame(cut = c("Idea", "Premiums", "Premioom", "VeryGood", "VeryGood", "Faiir"),
                clarity = rep(c("SI1", "SI2"),3),
                type = 1:6)
data("diamonds", package = "ggplot2")
diamonds <- diamonds[1:10,]

joined <- stringdist_inner_join(diamonds, d, by = c("cut", "clarity"))
joined
# # A tibble: 8 x 13
#   carat cut.x     color clarity.x depth table price     x     y     z cut.y    clarity.y  type
#   <dbl> <ord>     <ord> <ord>     <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <chr>     <int>
# 1 0.23  Ideal     E     SI2        61.5    55   326  3.95  3.98  2.43 Idea     SI1           1
# 2 0.21  Premium   E     SI1        59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31 Premiums SI2           2
# 3 0.21  Premium   E     SI1        59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31 Premioom SI1           3
# 4 0.290 Premium   I     VS2        62.4    58   334  4.2   4.23  2.63 Premiums SI2           2
# 5 0.26  Very Good H     SI1        61.9    55   337  4.07  4.11  2.53 VeryGood SI2           4
# 6 0.26  Very Good H     SI1        61.9    55   337  4.07  4.11  2.53 VeryGood SI1           5
# 7 0.22  Fair      E     VS2        65.1    61   337  3.87  3.78  2.49 Faiir    SI2           6
# 8 0.23  Very Good H     VS1        59.4    61   338  4     4.05  2.39 VeryGood SI1           5

subset(joined, clarity.x == clarity.y)
# # A tibble: 2 x 13
#   carat cut.x     color clarity.x depth table price     x     y     z cut.y    clarity.y  type
#   <dbl> <ord>     <ord> <ord>     <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <chr>     <int>
# 1  0.21 Premium   E     SI1        59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31 Premioom SI1           3
# 2  0.26 Very Good H     SI1        61.9    55   337  4.07  4.11  2.53 VeryGood SI1           5
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know how this could be adapted to a left_join, so as to not drop the missing cases of "clarity.y"?

Comment: `subset(joined, is.na(clarity.y) | clarity.x == clarity.y)`?